# Rails model associations and relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new in rails and currently trying to create an app but I can't seem to make it work. Here's my setup in model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :doctor, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes :doctor
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

In my users_controller, here's my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @user = current_user
    # render text: @user.inspect
    end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_doctor`
  end

  def create
    # binding.pry
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to dashboard_path
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end


  private 
        def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:role, :lastname, :firstname, :middlename, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :doctor_attributes => [:institution, :license_number])
        end
end
```

And my view:

```
<ul id="cbp-bislideshow" class="cbp-bislideshow">
    <li>
    <%= image_tag "blur1.jpg" %>
    </li>
    <li>
    <%= image_tag "blur2.jpg" %>
    </li>
</ul>

<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <div class="sign-up-wrapper divided-wrapper cf">

        <div class="left-section">
            <h3 class="section-title">JOIN US AND LET'S CHANGE THINGS</h3>


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="w49 pull-left">
                        <%= f.text_field :firstname, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'FIRSTNAME' %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="w49 pull-right">
                        <%= f.text_field :lastname, class: "input-text personal", placeholder: 'LASTNAME' %>
                    </div>
                    <%= f.hidden_field :role, value: :doctor %>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <%# f.text_field :specialization, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'SPECIALIZATION' %>
                </div>
            <%= f.fields_for :doctors do |p| %>
                <div class="row">
                    <%= p.text_field :institution, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'INSTITUTION' %>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <%= p.text_field :license_number, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'LICENSE NUMBER' %>
                </div>



            <% end %>


            <span class="remind bottom-message"> ONCE INSIDE DON'T FORGET TO UPDATE YOUR PROFILE WITH MORE DETAILS </span>
        </div>

        <div class="right-section">
            <h3 class="section-title"></h3>

            <div class="row">
                <%= f.text_field :email, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'EMAIL' %>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'PASSWORD' %>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "input-text personal ", placeholder: 'CONFIRM PASSWORD' %>
            </div>

            <div class="row cf">
                <%= f.submit class: 'btn-join btn', value: 'JOIN NOW' %>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <a href="#" class="btn-flip-social">SIGN UP WITH FACEBOOK / TWITTER ACCOUNT?</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Everytimie I execute these pieces, only the user model gets populated but not the doctors table? Is there something wrong on my code?

EDIT

> Changed doctors_attributes to doctor_attributes
>   changed @user.doctor.build`to @user.build_doctor

In the logs. I saw this error ---> Unpermitted parameters: doctors

So in theory, I think we know what's the problem, but I don't know how to fix this in the strong_parameters. Haven't tried a strong_parameter with accepted_nested_attributes_for in rails yet and this is my first time. Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the fields_for, replace :doctors with :doctor. Remember that you're doing a 1 to 1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

In your `user_params` model, the attribute `doctors_attributes` should be `doctor_attributes` since it's a `has_one` relationship. If it was a `has_many` relationship, it would be `doctors_attributes`. The part before `_attributes` would be whatever the association is named.

Another note: If you want to be able to *update* the doctor from the user form, you should also include the `id` in the `doctor_attributes` array. Though now that I think of it, it might only be a requirement on `has_many` nested associations. I've never tried doing a `has_one` without including the `id`.